# Login via curl and parsed data in php

Tags: php, curl

I try to login to a forum via curl. The forum generates a unique id everytime the login page is displayed. That kinda bugs me :( I am able to parse the id and use it. But somehow the id is changed when I try the actual login.

My code so far:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$url ="http://theforum.dk/index.php/Login/";
$cookie="cookie.txt";


//Fetching the id

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); (1)

$pos = strpos($output, '"t"')+11;
$pos2 = strpos($output, " />",$pos)-1;
$unique_id = substr($output, $pos,$pos2-$pos);

echo $unique_id; //Shows correct id

//Filling the POST array and submitting it

$arrSubmit="username=TESTUSER&action=login&password=TESTPASS&useCookies=1&url=&t=".$unique_id;


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrSubmit);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);


//Exectute and display result
echo curl_exec($ch); (2)
```

The output is something like "your id isn't valid anymore". The id at (1) differs from the id in the page source at (2) :(

The login form just a basic HTML form- Submitting the data isn't the problem, just using the fetched id from the start.

Do you guys got any idea?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Something to do with session variables? The server treats your requests as not coming from the same browser session I think.

Comment: This happens because when you parse the Unique ID the page is called and when you use the UniqueID to login, url is called again which generates the id again. This generally happens because of the Session Variables

Comment: Try using wire shark or some other low level utility to see what information gets exchanged with the server when you make the request the "normal" way (through browser) and compare it with the exchange when you use curl. The problem will then stare you in the face. I hope.

Comment: See if the q&a at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121280/how-to-let-curl-use-same-cookie-as-the-browser-from-php is helpful

Comment: Yep, Floris! Handling with a cookies just did it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my curl login example.

Good luck

```
        $login_email = 'mehmet';
        $login_pass = '112233';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mysites.com/giris');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'username='.urlencode($login_email).'&password='.urlencode($login_pass));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.mysites.com/package-details/237");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $curl_handle = curl_init ("http://www.mysites.com/package-details/237");
        curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $page       = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $page;
```