# Loading facebook content with curl

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying load facebook content with CURL, but the system is showing the login page instead of my timeline (also, I'm already signed in). Is something related to cookies? What I'm doing wrong? There's no errors in this code...

```
 $ch = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
 $header = array();
 $header[] = "Accept-Language: pt-br,pt;q=0.5"; 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
 $data = curl_exec( $ch );
 echo $data;
```

I hope you help me! Thank you

Comment: Your browser is logged in, but the server you're running this script on isn't.  See the post here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186168/php-curl-to-login-to-facebook

Comment: You're talking about two different universes here, @Erika. When you login through your web-browser this information is only visible for you. The same as when you try to access again from another browser in the same computer. So if you try from the server, it will require another authentication. Also, Facebook forbids scraping their information, as you can read here: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: @Rafael check term 2 `You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission.`. So if you ask nicely and give the reasons why, you're totally allowed.

Comment: So, is there no way?

Comment: There is a way, and I posted the answer in the first comment.

Comment: I believe that you didn't understood, i want inherit user session without doing the login again, the code in the first comment didn't worked

Comment: where are you passing username and password?

Comment: You may want to check here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121280/how-to-let-curl-use-same-cookie-as-the-browser-from-php

Comment: @unixmiah I don't want perform login, just get connected with my local session.

Comment: @FoulFoot I'll check about when get close home

Comment: @FoulFoot I've tried all scripts on this thread, not worked. I'm not automatically signed in

Comment: @Erika, check for Facebook APIs.

Comment: First I would try logging in via cURL without using a cookie, i.e. including your username and password.  Once you've accomplished that, then see about passing the session information.

Comment: _“What I'm doing wrong? ”_ - this: _“I'm trying load facebook content with CURL”_ Facebook does not want you to do that, so they have measures in place against it, of course. If you want to interact with content, users or anything else on Facebook in any automated way - then use their APIs. Everything else is against their ToS to begin with.

Answer (score -2):

php is server side and your server run your php code and after that return the output to browser. you need use in iframe for example for show facebook timeline.

Comment: Facebook is blocking my iframe :'/